# How many copies of auto-generated assignment operator in C++ (MS Visual Studio 2008)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, assignment-operator

If I have a POD (Plain Old Data) C++ class `Foo`, the common view is that one does not need to define a copy constructor nor an assignment operator for it, because C++ will do it automatically.

My question is, if `Foo.h` is included in multiple `.cpp` files and the `Foo` assignment operator is invoked in each of these `.cpp` files, will VS2008 generate multiple copies of the default assignment operator in the resulting `.obj` files? (I work on a very large project and I'm trying to reduce the size of binary files generated during the build.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator will be emitted into all of those .obj files (just like any other inline function). However, all but one of those functions will be discarded by the linker (if you have optimizations enabled).

Comment: Even if you have optimizations disabled, since otherwise you'd break the one definition rule.

Comment: @Xeo The one definition rule applies to source code, not what the compiler generates.  And the generated functions are `inline`, so you're allowed one definition per translation unit anyway.  A legal implementation could keep all of the copies.  (Most don't, but since such functions are `inline`, and for the most part, don't have their address taken, there's no need for the compiler to generate the out of line copy anyway---it just puts the code inline.)

Comment: @James: Oh, okay, then... ignore my comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the compiler, and the options used to invoke the compiler.
Compiler generated functions are considered to be declared `inline`, but
what that means in terms of generated code is totally up to the
compiler.

Most compilers have an option to make nothing inline (so you'll probably 
only get one copy).  Whether this will make the code smaller, however,
depends; if the generated constructor is very simple, generating it
inline may require less space than the code necessary to call a
non-inline copy.

Most compilers also have options to optimize for space, rather than
execution time (`/O1 /Os` for VC++, for example; or `-Os` for g++).  I'd
start by using these.

Comment: I know that optimization will remove them from the generated .exe or .dll file, but my question was about `.obj` files.